# React Component rerendering based on event of other user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, react-component

I have a screen where users need to wait a few seconds before the games start. During this stage, the react component needs to display no of players who joined the game using some game id. How do I update the screen of old users when new users join the screen? how to render the component when another user triggers an event and this change is reflected in all the user screens.thank you.

user   ------  activity --------- react component----------         comments

user A --> log's in --->   << user A joined >>     user A joined from computer A

user B  --> log's in --->  << user A, B joined >>   user B joined from compute B

user C --> log's in --->  << user A,B,C joined >>   use C jined from computer X

in this case c is able to see all the players, while b can see only a,b users and a can see only he logged. I want user A react component to be update  when user B logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can try socket.io, or you can use set interval method t update every 3 seconds there might be a delay though

Comment: I have thought about the option of time interval update for a particular interval, but I am looking for something real time is there any technique or library to acheive this ?, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You did not share any code, so it's hard to be specific, but I would suggest having a parent component and a child component as following:

- The parent component should have a state to keep track of the newly joined users, which should be forwarded to the child as props.
- The child should be able to update the parent state when a new user joins. This last part can be done by sending an arrow function (which updates the parent's state) to the child as another props.
- In the child component, you can render based on this props (parent's state). It should automatically re-render when it is updated.

Comment: hi reincore, i have update the question plese find it again

Answer (score 0):

You can tell React when you want to trigger a re-render because when React comes to render the component it will run `shouldComponentUpdate` and see if it returns true (the component should update, a.k.a. re-render) or false (React can skip the re-render this time). So you’ll need to overwrite `shouldComponentUpdate` to return **true** or **false** as needed to tell React when to re-render and when to skip.

Another way is to use State and mutate the state whenever the number of joined visitors change which will automatically trigger a re-render.

Comment: Hi plese find the question again again i have update it thans

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the best way to achieve this is using web sockets to ensure realtime communication between the clients. You could check out the [socket.io](https://socket.io/) library, it's pretty straightforward to use so it would at least let you know if web sockets are indeed the solution you need for this issue.